Elasticsearch Keystore error: Device or Resource Busy while upgrading
I have a multi node Elasticsearch cluster running on version 8.13.4.
The cluster needed Slack Integration and AD/LDAP integration so it also has elasticsearch.keystore file bind mount to it. The cluster is set up in a dockerized environment using docker compose.
While upgrading cluster to 8.14.2 we are facing the following error

e1      | Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.FileSystemException: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.keystore.tmp -> /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.keystore: Device or resource busy
e1      |   at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:100)
e1      |   at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:106)
e1      |   at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystem.move(UnixFileSystem.java:882)
e1      |   at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.move(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:309)
e1      |   at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.move(Files.java:1430)
e1      |   at org.elasticsearch.common.settings.KeyStoreWrapper.save(KeyStoreWrapper.java:519)
e1      |   at org.elasticsearch.common.settings.KeyStoreWrapper.save(KeyStoreWrapper.java:433)
e1      |   at org.elasticsearch.common.settings.KeyStoreWrapper.upgrade(KeyStoreWrapper.java:307)
e1      |   at org.elasticsearch.common.settings.KeyStoreWrapper.bootstrap(KeyStoreWrapper.java:237)
e1      |   at org.elasticsearch.server.cli.KeyStoreLoader.bootstrap(KeyStoreLoader.java:37)
e1      |   at org.elasticsearch.server.cli.ServerCli.execute(ServerCli.java:88)
e1      |   at org.elasticsearch.common.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:54)
e1      |   at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:85)
e1      |   at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:50)
e1      |   at org.elasticsearch.launcher.CliToolLauncher.main(CliToolLauncher.java:64)
e1 exited with code 1

It seems that the issue is related to bind mounting the elasticsearch.keystore file. This issue is mentioned here
Elastic Documentation
According to this if we mount the config directory directly it also asks for other config files as well , that we want to avoid.
What should be the workaround for this issue ?

I just encountered this while upgrading from 8.13.4 to 8.15.2. The answer is that the keystore internal format needs to be upgraded, and that would ordinarily happen transparently upon launch of Elasticsearch. Because you are mounting the keystore file directly (in my case also :ro), it is unable to do this transparent upgrade.
Somewhere along the way, you probably ran a command line, like this, right?:
docker run -it --rm -v /my/config/dir:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:<version> bin/elasticsearch-keystore create

To solve this issue, you'll need to run a similar command:
docker run -it --rm -v /my/config/dir:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:<version> bin/elasticsearch-keystore upgrade

After this is complete, the mount directly to the elasticsearch.keystore file should work again as it should.
